# Create a Samba share for guests

Tags: linux, networking, centos, network-shares, samba

Software versions:

```
CentOS 6.6 x64
Samba 4.0.0-66.el6_6.rc4 (from YUM)
```

Problem:

I am trying to create a Samba share on my CentOS server for guests/unauthenticated users. Using the configuration below, when I try to navigate to the share without authenticating, Windows prompts me for a username and password.

Requirement:

The share needs to be invisible when the user navigates to the root (i.e. \myserver) and the only way they can access it is via "\myserver\my_share\". Other shares need to ask the user for a username and password; this is the only share which is to be accessible by guests.

```
[global]
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        cups options = raw
        load printers = yes
        server string =
        default = global
        path = /home
        os level = 20
        winbind trusted domains only = yes
        security = user
        public = yes
        winbind use default domain = yes
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        max log size = 50

[my_share]
        browseable = no
        guest only = yes
        path = /home/my_home_path
```

Answer (score 2):

Changing the Samba [global] configuration to the following has resolved the issue. No software update was required.

```
[global]
    server string =
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 50
    guest ok = yes
    security = user
    map to guest = Bad Password
```

Answer (score 0):

Guest only and browseable = no should do what you need... Have you made sure that the permissions on your folder are appropriate? try running sudo chmod 777 /home/my_home_path

Comment: Folder is set to 777. Found this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134607/samba-no-longer-allowing-different-guest-account-per-share

Comment: I just noticed you have "winbind trusted domains only = yes" and winbind use default domain = yes" set those to no, restart sama and see if that does it.

Comment: `chmod 777`: nonononono! Never ever run `chmod 777`. It is practically never required! Not even for "testing purposes". If the file is readable, then it's readable. If it's writable by the `user` or `group` that need to write to it, then it's writable. There is absolutely zero need to give everyone write permissions, and forgetting to `chmod` it back to something sane is exactly how multinationals get hacked. Just don't do it. Ever. I wrote [an introduction of Unix permissions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35895436/660921). Please read it!